# Search bot for google - how can i search a new thing after each loop

Tags: python, selenium

1. I want to read new line every time from search.txt file
2. Bot goes to google.com and read line from search.txt file and this goes in loop.
3. I want to search new line everytime

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def find_element_send_text(location_of_the_element, type_message):
    """
        :param location_of_the_element: XPATH of te any web element.
        :return: Find element until it present on webpage and Type Text in it.
        """
    while True:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, location_of_the_element)
            element.clear()

            element.send_keys(type_message)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            # print(e)
            pass

def search_data():
    with open('search.txt') as f:
        data = f.read()
        proxies = data.split('\n')
        print(proxies)
    return proxies

search_data = search_data()[0].split(":")
search = search_data[0]

while True:
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
 driver.maximize_window()
 find_element_send_text("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']", search)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The bot is opening google.com and typing some text from search.txt file, which I created. This process is working in a loop, every time bot open google and search for some text which I pasted in search.txt, but it always ready first line of my search.txt file, i want the bot to read a new line every time for my search.txt file and type on google search.